# How to log out a user in a fluttter application depending on the way the user logged in?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have implemented two ways for users to log into my Flutter application. The first one works via email and password and the second one via Google. Now I am wondering, however, how to sign out a user. Currently, I am displaying a 'logged_in' page that simply displays "logged in". In the top right is a button that signs out the user. For the first login method, I am simply calling:

```
Future<void> signUserOut() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
```

Yet, this would only work for the first method and not for the second. I thought of some hard-coded ways like checking whether the email used to log in contains google.com, but I guess there must be an elegant way to approach this and somehow call `GoogleSignIn().signOut()` depending on the method used to log in.

Comment: You can call    await GoogleSignIn().signOut(); Inside signUserOut() just after FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(); It'll logout from app and no need to use method used to logIn.

Comment: Couldn't you just handle it by always calling both sign out methods? A main `signOut` function for your first auth type and a try/catch for the google auth. Then they would sign out anyways. Or you want to detect it for another reason?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know the [email address](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/email.html) of the user, because you can get it from the [User](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html) object, you can call [fetchSignInMethodsForEmail()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/fetchSignInMethodsForEmail.html) to check what provider(s) are associated with that email address. If an email address can be used only with one provider then it will be very simple. However, in the Firebase Android SDK for Android, the [fetchSignInMethodsForEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(java.lang.String)) is deprecated, due to the [Email Enumeration Protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection). So most likely that will also be happening in Flutter soon.

> I thought of some hard-coded ways, like checking whether the email used to log in contains google.com

That's not gonna always work because I can create a Firebase Account with email and password using a Gmail address.

Another solution might be to set a flag inside the user document, meaning a field that can hold the type of provider. So if the user is signed in with the email and password, then you only have to sign out the user from Firebase, otherwise, sign the user out from Firebase and Google.

Comment: Have you tried one of my solutions above, does it work for you?